# How to separate clients in an event based websocket implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I'm writing my own event-based websocket wrapper, based on the ws package for node and having trouble separating clients on the server side.

I set up a test scenario where my client emits a message to the server and the server sends a "ping" back to that same client.

What happens is that my test scenario works perfectly with the first connected client, but as soon as another client connects, emit messages from the first client will ping to the other client (messages from second client will correctly ping to the second client).

It feels like the WebSocket is somehow shared between the two clients but I can't seem to find where this is happening.

```
//SERVER CODE
let events = {};

function WebSockServer(port) {
  //Init server
  const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port,
    clientTracking: true
  }, () => {
    if (events['open']) {
      events['open'].callback();
    }
  });

  wss.on('connection', ws => {

    ws.id = uuidv4();
    let sock = new WebSock(ws, wss);

    if (events['connection']) {
      events['connection'].callback(sock);
    }

    ws.on('message', json => {
      console.log('received message from ' + ws.id);
      const message = JSON.parse(json);

      //Check flags
      for (let key in message.flags) {
        if (key === 'binary' && message.flags[key].length > 0) {
          message.flags[key].forEach(binary => {
            const parsed = Buffer.from(message.data[binary], 'utf-16');
            message.data[binary] = parsed;
          });
        }
      }

      //Check if event handler exists & check if event is only to be triggered once
      if (events[message.event] && !events[message.event].once) {
        events[message.event].callback(message.data);
      }
      else if (events[message.event] && events[message.event].once) {
        events[message.event].callback(message.data);
        delete events[message.event];
      }
      else {
        return;
      }
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
      if (events['close']) {
        console.log('client disconnected');
        events['close'].callback(ws.id);
      }

      wss.clients.delete(ws);
    });
  });

  //Create an event handler
  this.on = function on(event, callback) {
    events[event] = {callback, once: false};
    return this;
  }

  wss.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Server shut down.');
  });
}

function WebSock(ws, wss) {
  this.ws = ws;
  this.id = ws.id;

  //Create an event handler
  this.on = function on(event, callback) {
    events[event] = {callback, once: false};
    return this;
  }

  //Create an event handler for one time use
  this.once = function once(event, callback) {
    events[event] = {callback, once: true};
    return this;
  }

  //Emit message to socket
  this.emit = function emit(event, data) {
    let flags = {
      binary: []
    };

    //Check for binary data
    for (let key in data) {
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(data[key])) {
        const stringified = data[key].toJSON();
        data[key] = stringified;
        flags.binary.push(key);
      }
    }

    const payload = JSON.stringify({event, data, flags});
    this.ws.send(payload);
    return this;
  }

  //Emit message to specific socket
  this.emitTo = function emitTo(id, event, data) {
    let destination;
    let flags = {
      binary: []
    };

    //Find socket
    for (let socket of wss.clients) {
      if (socket.id === id) {
        destination = socket;
        break;
      }
    }

    //Check for binary data
    for (let key in data) {
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(data[key])) {
        const stringified = data[key].toJSON();
        data[key] = stringified;
        flags.binary.push(key);
      }
    }

    //Send message to socket
    if (destination) {
      //Check type
      if (typeof event != 'string' || typeof data != 'object') {
        throw new TypeError('event must be a string, data must be an object');
      }

      const payload = JSON.stringify({event, data, flags});
      destination.send(payload);
      return this;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = WebSockServer;
```

```
//CLIENT CODE
function webSock(url) {
  const ws = new WebSocket(url);

  let events = {};

  //Create an event handler
  this.on = function on(event, callback) {
    events[event] = {callback, once: false};
    return this;
  }

  //Create an event handler for one time use
  this.once = function once(event, callback) {
    events[event] = {callback, once: true};
    return this;
  }

  //Emit message to server
  this.emit = function emit(event, data) {
    let flags = {
      binary: []
    };

    //Check for binary data
    for (let key in data) {
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(data[key])) {
        const stringified = data[key].toJSON();
        data[key] = stringified;
        flags.binary.push(key);
      }
    }

    const payload = JSON.stringify({event, data, flags});
    ws.send(payload);
    return this;
  }

  ws.on('open', () => {
    if (events['open']) {
      events['open'].callback(ws);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', () => {
    if (events['close']) {
      events['close'].callback();
    }
  })

  ws.on('message', json => {
    const message = JSON.parse(json);

    //Check flags
    for (let key in message.flags) {
      if (key === 'binary' && message.flags[key].length > 0) {
        message.flags[key].forEach(buffer => {
          const parsed = Buffer.from(message.data[buffer]);
          message.data[buffer] = parsed;
        });
      }
    }

    //Check if event handler exists & check if event is only to be triggered once
    if (events[message.event] && !events[message.event].once) {
      events[message.event].callback(message.data);
    }
    else if (events[message.event] && events[message.event].once) {
      events[message.event].callback(message.data);
      delete events[message.event];
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = webSock;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This line of code `events[event] = {callback, once: false};` looks like it collides between different sockets.  `events[event]` is in the module scope, so the 2nd socket overwrites what the first socket did.  I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `events` object to know what to suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - unfortunately your suggestion doesn't fix the issue. I'm wrapping the ws protocol to resemble the socket.io library. This way I'll be able to do socket.emit('userDefinedEvent', data) while ws on its own is only capable of doing socket.send('message').

Comment: Maybe not the only issue, but it sure looks wrong to me and fits some of the symptoms. Why not fix that part of the design and then see where things stand.